# Google big query data server connection with cognos Analytics 1116

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jdbc, google-bigquery, cognos, cognos-bi

I am trying to create google big query data server connection with cognos analytics on cognos portal but i am getting below error . I have followed all steps . Placed json in the driver folder inside cognos install directory along with all the simba jdbc driver but not sure where i am missing .I have installed simba odbc drivers as well , system dsn is also showing simba driver but still getting connection refused. My cognos setup is installed on windows server 2019 data center which is Virtual Machine hosted on GCP and port 80,443 traffic is also enabled.

XQE-DS-0006 Unable to logon to the data source.
[Simba]JDBC Connection Refused: [Simba]JDBC Required Connection Key(s): OAuthServiceAcctEmail; [Simba]JDBC Optional Connection Key(s): AdditionalProjects, AllowLargeResults, DefaultDataset, EnableHighThroughPutAPI, FetchThreadsPerResultSet, ForceHTAPI, HighThroughPutMinTableSize, IgnoreTransactions, KMSKeyName, Language, LargeResultDataset, LargeResultsDatasetExpirationTime, LargeResultTable, MaxResults, OAuthAccessToken, OAuthClientId, OAuthClientSecret, OAuthRefreshToken, ProxyHost, RequestGoogleDriveScope, StringColumnLength, Timeout, TimestampFallback, useQueryCache

Comment: `JDBC Connection Refused` looks like an authentication error.  You can see the system dsn, but does it work?  If you're saying it doesn't (`system dsn is also showing simba driver but still getting connection refused`), this may not be a Cognos question.

Comment: i am testing via anonymous authentication. I setup big query data server connection on the On-premise server in the same way , tested using anonymous authentication and it was a success. Only problem is that now i am testing it on VM machine hosted on GCP but not sure if that will create error. One more to add , currently no AD is setup on the current VM server , thus no DNS or domain controllers. Can that cause issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following document which goes through the connection step by step.
[Google big query data server connection with cognos Analytics 1116](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70792033/google-big-query-data-server-connection-with-cognos-analytics-1116)

Its most likely the JSON file is not in the JDBC connection URL.